# Python strings, lists and process string in for loop

Tags: python, string

i am forcing myself to properly learn python, instead of just hacking on it when i want something.  going thru a book, and i want to process in a for loop, thats working with a list:

```
magicians = ['merlin', 'raistlin', 'gilgamesh', 'gandolf', 'sauron']
for mage in magicians:
    #print(mage)
    #print(mage.title() + ", is now a master and a planwalker")
    s = mage.find("merlin")
    print(s)
print("script has Finished...")
```

can't find, the way to search for the string as it process in the for loop. so i can mess with it. (maybe i am slow :))

what would be a good way to find which item in the list is being processed so i can do something different with each one?

Comment: In the loop mage will be equal to each of the strings in magicians. You don't need to “find” the string. You can compare with == in an if-sentence

Comment: FWIW, not a programming error, but the singular of "magicians" is "magician". i.e. `for magician in magicians:`

Comment: thats how the book actually had it, i just stuck "mage" in there to be easier on my eyes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be using an if statement as follows:

```
    magicians = ['merlin', 'raistlin', 'gilgamesh', 'gandolf', 'sauron']
for mage in magicians:
    #print(mage)
    #print(mage.title() + ", is now a master and a planwalker")
    if mage =="merlin":
        print(mage)
print("script has Finished...")
```

Comment: thanks that did the trick, i was looking at eval and find functions but they all return the binary or index values.

Comment: what about a regex like if mage == "mer*"?

Comment: @N6Ghost it won't work the if statement will consider the * as a character, not as a for all character

Comment: @N6Ghost i add another answer for your condition

Comment: @N6Ghost if my answer worked for you please upvote and accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for mage in magicians:
  if mage=="....":
      <do whatever you want to do with mage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexing the list. like..

```
magicians = ['merlin', 'raistlin', 'gilgamesh', 'gandolf', 'sauron']

length = len(magicians) 
for i in range(length): 
  #print(mage)
  #print(mage.title() + ", is now a master and a planwalker")
  if mage[i] == 'merlin':
    print(mage)
print("script has Finished...")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you this if you want to search for certain characters:

```
magicians = ['merlin', 'raistlin', 'gilgamesh', 'gandolf', 'sauron']
for mage in magicians:
    #print(mage)
    #print(mage.title() + ", is now a master and a planwalker")
    if"mer" in mage :
        print(mage)
print("script has Finished...")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the index using `enumerate`:

```
magicians = ['merlin', 'raistlin', 'gilgamesh', 'gandolf', 'sauron']
for index, mage in enumerate(magicians):
    #print(mage)
    #print(mage.title() + ", is now a master and a planwalker")
    if mage == "merlin":
        print(mage, 'Index of it is', index)
print("Done.")
```

Answer (score -2):

By tracking the index of the list ,we can find which item is being processed